# Get Tenant Id with new Azure Powershell commands (Az)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

In the Azure Active Directory Powershell module (AzureAD) you could use

```
$conn = Connect-AzureAd
```

and then get the Azure tenant ID using

```
$conn.tenantId
```

Straightforward enough.

With the new Azure Powershell module (Az) you can also capture the connection response

```
$conn = Connect-AzAccount
```

But there's no TenantId property. How do you get the TenantId ? `Get-AzTenant` brings back all potential tenants, and no flag for which one the current Azure connection is pointing to.

Comment: For what I've found you can use the "onmicrosoft" domain name of the tenant as a replacement for the tenantId in almost all case where you need the tenantId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Azure Powershell has shifted this information from top-level connection info to a more hierarchical representation using custom object types.

The *PSAzureProfile* type instance returned by Connect-AzAccount has a property called **Context** which is a *PSAzureContext* type. This object in turn has a **Tenant** property which is a *PSAzureTenant* type.

And there in that object is an **Id** property which has our currently selected Azure tenant ID for the current session.

Sample code:

```
$conn = Connect-AzAccount
$tenantId = $conn.Context.Tenant.Id
```

Hopefully documentation will improve on all of these types and how they're structured.